# event dispatch before rendering 404 page of "file not found"

Tags: magento

my intention is simple i just want to get my pages in different formats

e.g
**www.my-site.com/product-name.html** -- will load the page in html

but i want a json object when i type

**www.my-site.com/product-name.json**

if their is any event that magneto dispatch before rendering 404 page, that can be very helpful

or i have to rewrite app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/indexcontroller.php 
more or less

```
 public function defaultNoRouteAction()
{
    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.1','404 Not Found');
    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Status','404 File not found');

    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

but i don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar, exporting product data when calling an product-url with .xml instead of .html.

I've added an observer listening on product save event, that adds the product-xml URL into core_url_rewrite.
In that event, you have replace .htm(l) with .xml

e.g.

product-name.htm -> catalog/product/view/id/4 -> load product with ID 4 and render product view template, magento core

product-name.xml -> mycustommodule/product/view/id/4 -> load product with ID 4 and render XML, custom module

So you have to add another module called "mycustommodule" that handles the xml output.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

i solution that i found is following,it work perfectly but didn't know for sure is it the MAGNETO-WAY

i rewrite Mage_Cms_IndexController noRoute Method,

```
 public function noRouteAction($coreRoute = null) {

     // getting current url
      $url = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();



            if ( strstr($url,".jsonp") || strstr($url,".json") || strstr($url,".xml") ) {

             // geting file-type like json / xml
             $format =  substr(strrchr($url, "."),1);
             // product-handle 
              $elem = substr( strrchr($url, "/"),1,  strpos( strrchr($url, "/") , ".")-1 );

                switch ($format) {
                    case 'json': case 'JSON': case 'jsonp': case 'JSONP':
                        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json'); break;

                    case 'xml': case 'XML':
                        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/xml'); break;

                }

                 // loding product byproduct-handle
                $rewrite = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->loadByRequestPath($elem . ".html");
                $pid = $rewrite->getProductId();
                $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->loadByAttribute('url_key', $elem  );

                if (strpos($url,"hs_review")) { echo Mage::getModel("Hs_Json/review")->wrapper($pid,$format);return;}
                if ( $pid ) { echo Mage::getModel("Hs_Json/product")->wrapper($pid,$format);return; } 
                if ( $cat ) { echo Mage::getModel("Hs_Json/category")->wrapper($cat->getId(),$format);return;}


           } else {

            $this->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.1','404 Not Found');
            $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Status','404 File not found');

            $pageId = Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Cms_Helper_Page::XML_PATH_NO_ROUTE_PAGE);
            if (!Mage::helper('cms/page')->renderPage($this, $pageId)) {
                $this->_forward('defaultNoRoute');
            } 

           }

    }

}
```